# C program, scanf for a char, then reprinting it?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar, getch

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char fever, cough;

    printf("Are you running a fever? (y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c",&fever);

    printf("Do you have a runny nose/cough? (y/n)\n");
    scanf(" %c",&cough);

    printf("Please verify the folling information.\nFever: %c \nRunny nose/cough: %c \n,fever,cough");
return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get: 
12:2 warning:format '%c' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat]

What do I need to change? I know everything is systematically correct, I just need to use something else, and I can't find anything that specifically fixes my problem!

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Please verify the folling information.\nFever: %c \nRunny nose/cough: %c \n,fever,cough");
```

Above statement is systematically incorrect. Misplaced `"` .

MODIFY Like this

```
printf("Please verify the folling information.\n Fever: %c \nRunny nose/cough: %c \n ",fever,cough);
```

Answer (score 0):

Badly placed close quote.  Change \n,fever,cough" to \n",fever,cough

Answer (score 0):

You are not placing the ending `"` quote correctly

```
printf("Please verify the folling information.\nFever: %c \nRunny nose/cough: %c   \n",fever,cough);
                                                                                     ^ Close your quote here
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the fever or cough parameters to printf.  Just add fever and cough as parameters to printf function. Quote should be after text but before variables.